# New Site template throws error when used: failure to instantiate file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-template

I have created a new site based on the SP2010 Team Site template, customised the site and saved it as a template. When I try to create a fresh site with the template I get shown the following error message:

```
Failed to instantiate file "normal template.dot" from module "Published DocumentForms Document_Features\Office Document Content Type\Document Template": Source path "Features\Office Document Content Type\Document Template\normal template.dot" not found
```

I don't have this problem when I create sites with any other templates, just my new one. Clearly I have missed something from my template setup but I don't know what it is.